# My app crashes, when opening new Intent

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

my app crashes when am trying to open new Intent.

This is the *MainActivity.java* code:

```
package com.example.home.workouttrainings;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ImageView muscleup = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Muscleup);
        muscleup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent muscleup = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MuscleUp.class);
                startActivity(muscleup);
            }

        });



        ImageView planche = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Planche);
        planche.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent planche = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Planche.class);
                startActivity(planche);

            }

        });

        ImageView frontlever = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.FrontLever);
        frontlever.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent frontlever = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FrontLever.class);
                startActivity(frontlever);
            }
        });

        ImageView backlever = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BackLever);
        backlever.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent backlever = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Back_Lever.class);
                startActivity(backlever);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is the intent which crashes:

```
ImageView frontlever = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.FrontLever);
        frontlever.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent frontlever = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FrontLever.class);
                startActivity(frontlever);
            }
        });
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.home.workouttrainings">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MuscleUp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_muscle_up"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planche"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_planche"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Back_Lever"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_back__lever"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FrontLever"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_front_lever"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

FrontLever.java:

```
package com.example.home.workouttrainings;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class FrontLever extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_lever);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

}
```

Error logcat:

```
09-15 21:12:00.014 3554-3554/? I/TimeManager: receiver action = android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
09-15 21:12:00.023 4074-4074/? I/HwLauncher: Model  onReceive intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000014 (has extras) }
09-15 21:12:00.023 4074-4074/? I/HwLauncher: Model  onReceive user=UserHandle{0}
09-15 21:12:00.049 4074-4074/? I/TotemWeather: CityTimeView CityTimeView mCurrentViewMode = 10241
09-15 21:12:00.074 4074-4074/? I/TotemWeather: CityTimeView CityTimeView mCurrentViewMode = 10241
09-15 21:12:00.085 4074-4074/? I/TotemWeather: DateTimeManager send message delay millis = 60915 ms
09-15 21:12:01.830 3153-3485/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=2432 BSSID=f4:f2:6d:68:10:0e RSSI=-25 "RD32"WPA_PSK
09-15 21:12:02.521 2498-2498/? E/Thermal-daemon: [charger_ic] temp_new :37  temp_old :38
09-15 21:12:02.521 2498-2498/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [charger_ic] temp :37  report_threshold:1
09-15 21:12:02.725 9393-9393/? I/wpa_supplicant: set current WIFI status to BT!
09-15 21:12:02.751 9393-9393/? I/wpa_supplicant: set current WIFI status to BT!
09-15 21:12:03.153 6098-11161/? I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
09-15 21:12:03.667 3153-3472/? E/InputReader: QEEXO fs_classify_touch NULL, not calling FingerSense
09-15 21:12:03.750 3153-3472/? E/InputReader: QEEXO fs_touch_up NULL, not calling FingerSense
09-15 21:12:03.765 3153-3153/? I/SendBroadcastPermission: action:android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED, mPermissionType:0
09-15 21:12:03.767 3153-3167/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.huawei.lcagent.client.LogCollectManager.getUserType()' on a null object reference
09-15 21:12:03.767 3153-3167/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.util.ReportTools.getUserType(ReportTools.java:86)
09-15 21:12:03.767 3153-3167/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.util.ReportTools.isBetaUser(ReportTools.java:73)
09-15 21:12:03.767 3153-3167/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.util.ReportTools.report(ReportTools.java:58)
09-15 21:12:03.767 3153-3167/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.util.HwUserBehaviourRecord.appExitRecord(HwUserBehaviourRecord.java:65)
09-15 21:12:03.767 3153-3167/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$UiHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:1523)
09-15 21:12:03.768 3153-3167/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-15 21:12:03.768 3153-3167/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
09-15 21:12:03.768 3153-3167/? W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
09-15 21:12:03.768 3153-3167/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
09-15 21:12:03.768 3153-3167/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
09-15 21:12:03.768 16909-16909/com.example.home.workouttrainings I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16909 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please add error logs

Comment: post error log what is the error

Comment: Way too much code. Way too little stacktrace. Limit your post to the code that is causing the issue and the stacktrace.

Comment: This is the error log: 13566-13566/com.example.home.workouttrainings I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13566 SIG: 9

Comment: update you question by adding complete 10 to 20 lines logcat

Comment: I don't think that Logcat is related to your app. None of your code touches a `android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED`

Comment: My guess is that `activity_front_lever.xml` does not contain an `@+id/toolbar`

Comment: Yes there is no toolbar, but the activity.planche.xml also not contains toolbar... and it works

Comment: How can i limit my post to the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i fixed it...
So the problem was in my xml code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="700dp"
    tools:context="com.example.home.workouttrainings.BackLever"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_back__lever"
    android:background="#515151">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/rweight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/rheight">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:src="@drawable/rsz_backlever"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Muscles:"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:textColor="#67ff34"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:src="@drawable/chestm"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/shoulders" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:src="@drawable/abs" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Legs Bent Back Lever  "
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textColor="#67ff34"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="At least: 25-30 seconds"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:textColor="#277bfa"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Straddle Back Lever  "
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textColor="#67ff34"
            android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="At least: 10-15 seconds"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#277bfa"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Program"
            android:id="@+id/btnprogramfl"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="#67ff34"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Back Lever"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="#277bfa"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and on this line:

```
tools:shownIn="@layout/activity_back__lever"
```

Yes there is two "__"